# Cannot grab the parent of an event target in Internet Explorer 11 in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer-11, jquery-events

```
const findClosestParent = (startElement, fn) => {
  const parent = startElement.parentElement;
  if (!parent) return undefined;
  return fn(parent) ? parent : findClosestParent(parent, fn);
};

$document.on('click', event => {
  let target = event.target;
  if (findClosestParent(target, parent => parent.classList.contains('.calendar')) {
    // do some things
  }

});
```

I'm trying to find if an element is within another element.  I can't do that with closest in Internet Explorer 11.  So I went the route of creating a recursive searching up the DOM tree function.  However, I also cannot simply grab the parent element of the targeted event element in Internet Explorer 11 in an angular js controller using jQuery's `event.target property`.  This does snippet not work because   `startElement.parentElement` in `findClosestParent` is always null no matter what I click.  Also, `startElement.parentNode` is null.  `event.currentTarget.parentNode` is null.  I have tried so many things.  Nothing works.  Another thing I tried, I cannot simply add an id to the divs I am trying to select and use a pure vanilla js `getElementById` query selector because these elements are abstracted away in a 3rd party library.  I would very much so like to be able to use event target or something similar to get me the dang element in IE11.

I think it boils down to the fact that, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement, for IE, `parentElement` is "Only supported on `Element`".  Thats what it says... what that means is that I think internet explorer doesn't think `event.target` is an "`Element`".

Comment: did my answer finally solved your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution using angularjs and jQuery Core.

Try clicking somewhere inside and outside the element with the `calendar` class.

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', []);

    angular.
        module('app')
        .controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $(document).on('click', function ($event) {
                var nativeElement = $event.target;
                if ($(nativeElement).closest('.calendar').length) {
                    console.log('Inside a calendar');
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Outside a calendar');
                }
            });
        }])

})();
```

```css
.calendar {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.widget {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="module.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="myController">
    <div class="calendar">
      <div class="ancestor-2">
        <div class="ancestor-1">
          Calendar
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="widget">
      <div class="ancestor-2">
        <div class="ancestor-1">
          Not a calendar
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nw2xda7q/3/)